# stacking x and y labels when graphing large amounts of data-R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph a dataframe which is 1100x2 large. Because of the large amount of data, I find that `ggplot` stacks the labels. Is there a way to avoid this or just delete the labels altogether? Here is my graph:

[image: My graph]

and here is my code:

```
ggplot(data=`Rsa19766.01-s00-m01-1`, 
       aes(x=`Rsa19766.01-s00-m01-1`$Wavelength,
           y=`Rsa19766.01-s00-m01-1`$Reflection, 
           group=1,shape=".")) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle("Cary Ref")
```

Comment: Looks like your data columns are `factor` or `character`. `ggplot` will do an excellent job labeling appropriately if you convert those to continuous data types. (From your graph it looks like you are dealing with continuous rather than categorical data.)

Comment: ...also, you should never, ever refer to variables in your data frame via `$` when mapping them inside of `aes()`. It should always be `aes(x = Wavelength,...)` etc.

Comment: ...and it's hard to do more than those two pieces of advice without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). Can't even tell what data types you currently have...

Comment: I apologize for not giving a repoducible example. Your advice worked though, thank you so much. Do you know how to close a question, or indicate it has been answered?